# ARM Fast Model Simulation on Linux - Compiling the hello world

Tags: linux, arm, fast-model

I am trying to use ARM foundation model for aarch64 simulation on Linux (Ubuntu 20.4). Arm has provided a simple hello world program source and binary to run on the fast model. The binary executes well on the simulator. The example folder contains a make file. The main statements are

`armcc --cpu=8-A.64.no_neon -g -O2 -c -o $@ $<`

`armlink --cpu=8-A.64.no_neon --ro-base 0x80000000 -o $@ $^`

Is it possible to build this sample using `aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc`? I tried with `aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc hello.c -o hello --static`. The simulation starts, it is not showing any output. Is this the right way? Any hint is greatly appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

`aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc` is not an embedded compiler, I think what you need is [arm-gnu-toolchain-11.3.rel1-x86_64-aarch64-none-linux-gnu.tar.xz](https://developer.arm.com/-/media/Files/downloads/gnu/11.3.rel1/binrel/arm-gnu-toolchain-11.3.rel1-x86_64-aarch64-none-elf.tar.xz?rev=73ff9780c12348b1b6772a1f54ab4bb3&hash=57C22236F869382FCF207B9A011E37D6438714EF) if you are building on x86-64 Linux.